# What happened to the comments section on the blog?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, blog

The most recent [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/why-stack-overflow-is-a-good-workplace-for-women/) seems to have lost its comment section at the bottom. What happened to it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you may have heard, [the blog was recently revamped](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog/) after running on WordPress for 7 years. As part of this, comments were transitioned to Disqus.

It's a promising change... But there are some teething pains. Specifically, options for moderating comments are very different now, and there are only a tiny handful of people with access to them - only one of whom was around when the latest blog post went up. So when life necessitated his presence elsewhere, he turned off the comments rather than leave the blog untended. Later on, we removed the comments entirely rather than leaving a thread that no one else could contribute to.

Naturally, this isn't a long-term solution to anything; we'll have to build a proper moderation team for the blog and probably find a way to allow authors to moderate comments on their own posts to some extent (this was how it worked under the old system) - in other words, a system that *scales* with the increasing volume of content being posted there. But until these kinks get worked out, disabling commentary is better than the alternative; as sad as a blog without comments may be, it pales in comparison to [the horror that besets unmoderated comments](http://blog.codinghorror.com/please-read-the-comments/).

Until then, if you have questions or concerns about this or any blog post, don't hesitate to raise them *here*, on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why do you guys now disable comments? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/11/How-We-Talk-About-Diversity-at-Stack-Overflow/?cb=1.  Why are you even bothering running on a different platform..you guys could use the stackexchange engine as a blogging tool.  You've got commenting down pat...

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269257/the-latest-blog-post-doesnt-allow-comments (tl;dr: moderating Disqus is a major annoyance.) Anyone's welcome to discuss any blog post *here* if they want, and I agree it'd be nice to have some better integration there.

Comment: I don't get it.  [This blog post from a week ago](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/29/making-remote-work-behind-scenes/) has comments enabled. [This one from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/03/mapping-ecosystems-software-development/) does also. And yet today's blog post ["3 Way You Can Be an Ally to Women in Tech"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/04/3-ways-can-ally-women-tech/) has comments *disabled.*  Looking for why, I find this post, and a two year old blog post on the *same* topic with comments disabled.  **Can you please reassure me there is no political motivation?**

Comment: Probably not, @Wildcard. But here's a relevant link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357417/why-are-comments-closed-on-the-latest-blog-post