# The latest blog post doesn't allow comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, blog

[The Nov 11 Stack Overflow blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/11/How-We-Talk-About-Diversity-at-Stack-Overflow) doesn't include the comments section. I think that this is a bug, since all other posts do have this section, and I don't think that the Stack Overflow team has suddenly decided to disallow commenting for new posts.

Comment: It's not a bug. Posts about women in the workplace and diversity and political correctness tend to provoke heated debates.

Comment: I understand. But I just wanted to say that I was interested in the outcome of the "English as a second language" discussion since I am not a native English speaker. I considered contacting directly the post author, but the only contact information available is her Twitter account.

Comment: Not sure how internal SO discussions may be of general interest.

Comment: I just thought that perhaps part of the discussion results could be interesting and publicly shared. I'm sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: Here's how we talk about diversity--by closing the comment section.  Quite welcoming.

Comment: @Won't It's not a discussion starter. It's just a blog post describing how we do a particular thing within the company. If y'all want to discuss anyway, you obviously know where meta is.

Comment: Discuss filthy dirty politics?  Do I really seem that degenerate?  What do I look like, a PHP developer???

Comment: @Won't, and [they did it again today](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/04/3-ways-can-ally-women-tech/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Comments are allowed or disallowed on blog posts on a case-by-case basis. Based on our past experience with posts on this topic, we've decided to close comments on that particular blog post as a precaution. We don't want to prohibit discussion about the post and its content, but we do want to make sure we can have those discussions in an environment like this one on meta, where there are better controls for a reasonable conversation on a controversial topic.

Comment: Agreed, but maybe show a note like "Comments on this blog post are currently disallowed", so that people won't wonder?

Comment: I'm not opposed to "Comments are off, head to [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) if you've got questions or wish to have a discussion about this post." It's not that we mind talking to people about what we post, we just hate doing it on a comment system.